# How do I know if I'm using copy or move?

Tags: c++, c++14, move-semantics

Do I understand it right that the C++14 standard library uses move semantics? In other words, can I be confident that I am using a move instead of a copy in the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std::string_literals;

std::vector<std::string> greeting()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vs {"hello"s, "world"s};
    return vs;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> s = greeting();
    std::cout << s[0] << " " << s[1] << "\n" ;
}
```

Is there a way I can check?

How about in the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std::string_literals;

class Greeting {
    public:
    std::string first, second;
    Greeting() { first = "hello"s ; second = "world"s ;};
};

Greeting greetingc()
{
    Greeting g;
    return g;
}

int main()
{
    Greeting g = greetingc();
    std::cout << g.first << " " << g.second << "\n" ;
}
```

Move, or copy?

Comment: Where exactly do you want to check? What line of code should be a move?

Comment: @rubenvb I mean that when the return statement is called from either of greeting(0 or greetingc(), what does the program do: does it copy the object (a potentially expensive operation) or does it move the object (a cheap operation).

Comment: In general, whenever temporary object are created, which you do not have access to, are good candidate for `move semantics`.

Comment: Maybe [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476393/how-to-know-or-test-if-a-given-type-is-going-to-be-moved).

Answer (score 2):

In most cases there is not much difference between copy and move. It is only interesting when you have ownership ower something which you do not want to duplicate. Like a socket or memory allocated to the object. So only interesting when something is both expensive (like copy a huge chunk of memory when you need only one of that) and you have to take care of ownership (not having two pointers pointing to the same memory, or a socket, etc...).

In both of your examples what is most likely to happen is that the compiler will do RVO return-value optimization, which removes the need of a copy or move. Vector defines move so the compiler will use move semantics whenever it can (rvalue semantics), and you can force it with std::move. But neigher of your examples will be any faster because of it. [Read more about move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics).

If you are curious you can implement both copy and move and place write to the console from them.

```
Greeting(const Greeting& g)
{
    std::cout << "Copy";
    // Copy it
}

Greeting(Greeting&& g)
{
    std::cout << "Move";
    // Move it
}
```

Usually this is what happens.

```
Greeting foo(){ Greeing a; return a; }
Greeting a; // Normal construction
Greeting b(a); // Copy of 'a'
Greeting c(std::move(a)); // Move, 'a' will be changed
Greeting d(foo()); // Move from rvalue which is returned from foo() unless RVO kicks in
```